# UDP packet encryption

Tags: python, ssl, udp

This appears to be reasonably trivial if using the ssl module for TCP communication, but how would encrypted communication be done via UDP?

Can the ssl module still be used? if so, what steps would need to be performed for the client and server to be in a position where data can be sent to-and-fro as normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) is a TLS (aka SSL) derivative designed for use over datagram transports, like UDP.

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) supports DTLS starting in 0.9.8, using `DTLSv1_METHOD` instead of `SSLv23_METHOD` or `TLSv1_METHOD` or similar.

Comment: It doesn't look promising, I'm have a poke around the pyOpenSSL documentation at the moment and DTLSv1_METHOD isn't listed alongside the SSLv23 and TLSv1 methods.

Comment: Argh, you're right.  The ChangeLog implied that DTLS constants were added, but I checked out the sources now and DTLSv1_METHOD isn't there.  It looks like it could be easy to add, though.  [edit]  https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/454737

Comment: The OpenSSL's DTLS implementation as it stands now seems quite unreliable. I created on project based on it and it suffers from unavoidable losses of DTLS sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pyCrypto or [ezPyCrypto](http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/) to manually encrypt/decrypt the packets.

Comment: How?  Do this individually per packet?  Huge overhead (especially given datagram's size limitations) with public and keys included in every packet.  Work at a higher level and split up the results into multiple packets?  Nope, UDP is unreliable and dropping/reordering will screw up your decryption stream.

Comment: Don't need to send keys with each packet... why not send the pub key ahead of time?

Comment: Oops, should just be key above.